# Mock a call to a mocked class with functional interface parameter

Tags: mockito

I have this method that I need to mock:

```
public static void myMethod(Supplier<String> supplier, boolean flag) {
   // ...
   supplier.get();
   // ...
}
```

I need to mock this method which receives a Supplier, and I would like to mock it by just calling the given Supplier. So I did like this:

```
    Mockito.when(myMockedClass.myMethod(ArgumentMatchers.<Supplier<Integer>> any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.anyBoolean())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
                Supplier<Integer> command = invocation.getArgument(0);
                return command.get();
            });
```

This works, but I am asking if there is a shorter way to do this.

Comment: That's how I would do it.

Comment: You mock a static method and the mocked answer is identical to the original code. I would't mock that method at all

Comment: i have just updated the piece of code for myMethod, actually it is doing more things